# Gun Homicide Rate per US County

Tags: usa, crime, county

Does anyone know where I might find data for the number of gun homicides per county in 2020, for the entire United States? I can settle for another year if 2020 is not available and I can settle too for homicides instead of gun homicides.

I have found this but its per state:
https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2019/crime-in-the-u.s.-2019/tables/table-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a county based dataset of the number of deaths due to homicide per 100,000 population from 2013-2019. The data source is National Center for health statistics.

Dataset Link:  https://www.countyhealthrankings.org/explore-health-rankings/measures-data-sources/county-health-rankings-model/health-factors/social-and-economic-factors/community-safety/homicides